# Idiomatic/Groovy way to add two maps, either of which may be null

Tags: dictionary, groovy, idioms

I have the following map:

```
configs = [
    common : [
            foo : '123',
            bar : '456'
    ],
    dev : [
            foo : '789',
            bar : '012'
    ],
    test : null
]
```

When I add `dev` to `common`, it works great - the values from `common` are overridden by the values from `dev`. Just what I want.

```
dev = configs['common'] + configs['dev']
println dev
// --> [foo:789, bar:012]
```

However, if I try the same with `test`, I get the following error:

> groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method java.util.LinkedHashMap#plus.
>   Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
>       [interface java.util.Collection]
>       [interface java.util.Map]

I can make it work by doing something like the following:

```
test = [:]
test = configs['common']==null ? test : test + configs['common']  // First add common bits
test = configs['test']==null ? test : test + configs['test']  // Then override with environment specific bits
println test
// --> [foo:123, bar:456]
```

But this seems ugly and bloated.

Can someone with better Groovy-fu show me a nicer way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Elvis operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_elvis_operator) to bring an empty map to the equation when `config['test'] == null`. Consider the following example:

```
def configs = [
  common : [
    foo : '123',
    bar : '456'
  ],
  dev : [
    foo : '789',
    bar : '012'
  ],
  test : null
]


def dev = configs['common'] + (configs['dev'] ?: [:])
println dev

def test = configs['common'] + (configs['test'] ?: [:])
println test
```

Output:

```
[foo:789, bar:012]
[foo:123, bar:456]
```

You can use it whenever you expect that one value can be represented by `null`.

Comment: Aargh, I was so close. I tried that, but didn't enclose in (). Now, for bonus points, I guess I could I do the same for the common part (in case that is null)?

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted - Thank you.

Comment: Correct. If `config['commons']` may be null then wrapping it with `?:` is a good idea.